# Set groups polices on windows - active directory from PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, windows-server

How I can set groups polices on Windows Server - Active Directory, using or from **PHP**.

I want push to Active Directory any groups polices, for example: max characters password permit, set ip authorizes to longing, so on...

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Write your own API for that!

Comment: Exactly, how I interacting with AD from PHP? what are the function AD for that? Thank for your comment.

Comment: I'm using adLDAP class and I create: groups users, users, so on; and I can't set groups polices :-(

Comment: Knowing how stubborn Microsoft Technologies are, I doubt that you can achieve your goals without using C#. Maybe you should consider [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [adLDAP](https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP/wiki/adLDAP-Developer-API-Reference) and [PHP's native LDAP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ldap.php) don't support this, you can write a PowerShell script and execute it from PHP using the [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function.

See [PowerShell Group Policy reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx) to get started. Searching the net will give you some ready to use examples of how to assign policies to a group using PowerShell.

Good luck!